# NServiceBus - System.InvalidOperationException: No destination specified for message(s):

Tags: c#, nservicebus

I have an Endpoint I have configured ASA_Server. It just processes messages.

I'm getting the following message

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No destination specified for message(s):
```

Setup as follows:

```
 Configure.With()
            .LicensePath(LicenseFile)
            .CastleWindsorBuilder(WindsorAccessor.Instance.Container)
            .DefineEndpointName("phoenix.nservicebus.onevue")
            .Log4Net()
            .XmlSerializer()
            .MsmqTransport()
            .IsTransactional(true)
            .PurgeOnStartup(false)
             .Log4Net()
            .UnicastBus();
```

A website puts messages into the queue for this endpoint to process.  Whilst operating on the message I get the stated error.

Had this working prior to a big refactor, appreciate the help - Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry found the error - my bad - in my refactoring I recursively called the same 'Send' method in the handler - thus resending the same message once the current one had been published - leading to a never ending loop - all fixed now

Comment: The exception should be blamed because it does not have anything to do with what was happening.

Answer (score 1):

Not a fan of NServiceBus in any way, but here are my two cents: That error is happening at run time right? It most likely means that you're sending a message type which you forgot to add to the NServiceBus conf file. It is raising that exception because it does not know what to do with the message.

Comment: Marco, could you please get in touch with me and explain your perspectives on NServiceBus? udi.dahan@nservicebus.com

Comment: OK - I've read that. What I don't understand is why you seem to be "going out of your way" to say bad things about it.

Comment: @UdiDahan I say bad things based on my experience. Don't take me wrong, people are free to like or dislike something, and as the creator of NServiceBus you have to live with it. How many people say bad things about WCF, Silverlight, HTML, Javascript, Java, C#, .NET... Like I said before, I've worked with event soa before where we had our own custom components: Queues, Saga managers working around WFC and it worked pretty well, I simple see no benefit in using NServiceBus and I don't like it, that's it.

Comment: @UdiDahan looking back at it, I was very very arrogant and guess what, been using NServiceBus for almost 6 years now...

Comment: Marco, good hearing back from you. I'd be happy to hear more about your experiences over the past 6 years. Feel free to ping me over Twitter, LinkedIn, or email.

Comment: @UdiDahan I am sure you have heard about a few ones, like the discussion over the usage of the async name :) All in all it's good to see the work your guys are doing overall - adding expressions to speed up things even further was top :)